# mongodb equivalent to sql WITH clause?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query something with SQL's WITH clause, query:

```
with t1 as(
select field1, field2, calculatedField
from table1
),
t2 as (
select field1, field2, calculatedField
from table 2
)
select a.*, b.*
from t1 as a
left join t2 as b on a.field1 = b.field1
```

how can I achieve this in mongodb? i can't find an operator in mongodb for `WITH`

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/